# Salvar/Recuperar arquivos com extensão PDF

Tags: javascript, c#, sql-server, asp.net-core

Para salvar arquivos com extensão **PDF** no banco de dados é necessário fazer a conversão para *base 64*?
Ou teria alguma outra maneira de salvar esse tipo e sua recuperação para visualização?

O código que eu tenho a baixo, faz a conversão de imagem para *base 64*, onde a recuperação das imagens está devidamente tratada.
Ao salvar um arquivo PDF ele converte o mesmo, porém na recuperação do arquivo fica assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
               {
                clientesFotos.File.CopyTo(stream);
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, stream.ToArray());
                clientesFotos.DocumentoString = Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());
                stream.Dispose();
                stream.Close();
                 }
```

Retorno dos arquivos convertido da *base 64*

```
 function exibirDocumentos(img) {
                //$("#overlay").show();
                $("#imagem").attr("src", "data:image/jpeg;base64," + document.getElementById(img).value);
            }
```

Comment: A extensão do arquivo é uma referência para o usuário final e para o Sistema Operacional. O computador se importa com o conteúdo que existe de fato no arquivo. Por exemplo, você pode criar um arquivo de texto, escrever seu nome nele e salvar com o nome e extensão "minha_foto.jpg", mas isso não vai tornar o seu arquivo texto em uma imagem. No máximo o Sistema vai tentar tratar o seu arquivo de texto como uma foto e não irá conseguir. No seu caso, o conteúdo binário do arquivo é uma **imagem** ou um **PDF**?

Comment: Você está salvando o arquivo no banco de dados em base64?

Comment: @RodrigoK.B Sim! Porém na recuperação para visualização do mesmo, ele nao exibe. Diferente de jpeg, png...

Se eu fosse converter o arquivo pdf em jpeg/png para depois recuperar como está atualmente, como faria isso ?

Comment: Acho que o seu problema não é conversão, e sim como está esse base64. Esse código c# da sua pergunta, você usa ele para recuperar o  arquivo para download, ou para salvar no banco de dados? Se possível poste uma stirng base64 de algum arquivo de teste seu, exatamente como está salvando no banco de dados.

Comment: Não faz o mínimo sentido querer colocar um PDF na página como se fosse imagem. O problema não tem nada a ver com base 64 ou com o armazenamento.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se você está salvando como PDF, não pode exibir com o content-type image/jpeg.

Para exibir como image/jpeg, primeiro terá que converter o PDF para jpeg.

Comment: O contente-type está passando como "application/pdf" porém está sendo convertido a base 64, minha dúvida é se este é um caminho correro para trabalhar como armazenamento de dados pdf

Answer (score 0):

O melhor caminho para salvar arquivos, é salvar no disco rígido.

Porém dependendo do banco de dados, tem a opção de salvar como `varbinary(max)` (FILESTREAM ou BLOB), dispensando a conversão, podendo salvar diretamente os bytes no banco de dados. Quando for salvar ou recuperar, é dispensada a conversão em BASE64.